# Visual Studio Team Services Build Error on "System.Web.http" version

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, msbuild, azure-devops, build-error

I have few projects in my solution referring Syste.Web.Http and Formatting binary. Things are fine few days back but last week my Team Services build started failing without any changed made on ref: and it gives me below error

> Assembly 'Microsoft.CloudOA.Wizard' with identity 'Microsoft.CloudOA.Wizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http' with identity 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

However, the same project is building fine in locally. I tried looking into all projects and made sure none of my project is using 4.0.0. But no luck. Can some one please help me to get rid of this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you check all bin folders. I mean it can be changed in bin folder, but reference in project can be still to 4.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try running "Update-package" command for all your projects from "VS\Tools\Nuget Package Manager\Package Manager Console" to update the referenced packages to the latest version.